# FILO java writing strategy in a text file

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to apply the "First In last out" strategy in a text file

Assuming that I have a file containing some "measurements", and I don't want it to contain more than 10 lines, I'm accessing to it to :

- If < 10 = insert a value and write lines in other support
- If >= 10 = insert a value and write only the last 10 lines (and delete others)

To make it simple, assuming that my file look like
(to not charge it some much, I'll just put some line break as it was in java)

File :

```
1 "\n" 2 "\n" 3 "\n" 4 "\n" 5 "\n" 6 "\n" 7 "\n" 8 "\n" 9 "\n" 10
```

Now I want to insert a new data in the file and get the last 10, new data is **11** :

My file should look like :

```
2 "\n" 3 "\n" 4 "\n" 5 "\n" 6 "\n" 7 "\n" 8 "\n" 9 "\n" 10 "\n" 11
```

Is there a way to do this in java ?

Comment: You specify in the first line "First In last out". But in the rest of the description and in the example you give, you are doing first in first out. Which do you want?

Comment: Not a simple one if that's what you mean. A file is stored as byte-sequence, not a sequence of lines. You'll have to read the entire file, delete entries as appropriate and write the entire content back. You may want to take a look at circular files and random-access files.

Comment: @ControlAltDel : no it's First in Last out, the last value inserted will be last value rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure is.

- Write a method that reads that file into a helpful data structure, for example a `List<Integer>`
- Then manipulate the content of that data structure, for example using [List.remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) to remove the first entry; and then append that one new entry
- Then write that data structure back into your file

Comment: May works ! Thanks ! I was searching for an algorithmic help, not a code :)